# What cookies does Drupal use?

Tags: cookies

I need help with this..
A client wants to write a privacy policy for their site and they are asking what cookies Drupal uses so that they can include a description of them in the policy.
Which cookies does Drupal 7 use, and what are their functions? or at least the list of all cookies that Drupal Core uses.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Which cookies are used depends from the modules you install. It's not possible to give a list of all the cookies used from modules, and it would not make any sense to give such a list.

Comment: No, but it would make sense to define a list that comes in core.  Why would you downvote this?  This would be great information.

Comment: I think the same, it's a great information. I need at least the core cookies.

Comment: The core cookies as in those set by the core "required" modules that can't be disabled? `has_js` and a session cookie, that's it I believe. From there it depends what modules you enable (core comment sets one under the right circumstances, same for core contact, contrib modules do whatever they want). You can't have just a flat list of "what cookies does Drupal use?" because it changes depending on your configuration, even without any contrib modules installed

Comment: Got it, I just installed the firebug addon on Mozilla and helped me to identify some. I assume that I need to check which modules that I've installed use cookies no?